# Is it possible to approve comments via YouTube API?

Tags: python, api, youtube

just a quick question does anyone know if it's possible to approve comments via YouTube API? I swear I've seen a tutorial on how to do it before, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it and I'm beginning to think it's actually not possible and I've just got it mixed up with something else.

For the record I'm using the Python version of YouTube API v3, if that's important at all.